# How to wrap a C++ function?

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to wrap a `c++` function called `i_receive()` by following [this](http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2014/09/05/how-to-wrap-a-system-call-libc-function-in-linux/) tutorial, I first created a `wrap.c` file, the content of this file is like this:

```
int i_receive(const uint32_t *f, int32_t t){

    static int (*real_i_receive)(const uint32_t *, int32_t)=NULL;
    printf("hello world");
    return real_i_receive;
}
```

I compiled this file with `gcc -fPIC -shared -o wrap.so wrap.c -ldl`, when I used the `LD_PRELOAD` to run some C++ code with `LD_PRELOAD=/full/path/to/wrap.so ./mycppcode` I got this message:

> ERROR: ld.so: object '/full/path/to/wrap.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored`.

I was guessing the reason might be that the wrap file is a C file, and I'm using it with C++ code, am I right?

I changed the file to `wrap.cc` with the same content, when compiling in the same way as before, I got:

> ERROR: invalid conversion from `'int (*)(const uint32_t*, int32_t)' to 'int'`

Comment: The error you got pretty much explains is:
error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(const uint32_t*, int32_t)' to 'int'

You are returning a function pointer, real_i_receive of type int (*)(uint32_t*,int32_t) into an int.

You probably meant to return the VALUE of real_i_receive, in which case you need to change your return statement to the following:

return real_i_receive(f,t)

Comment: The final error is because you need to call the function with `return real_i_receive(f,t);` not return a pointer to it. After setting the pointer to something non-null, as the tutorial describes, of course.

Comment: @IshayPeled the compile error in the c file doesn't exist, but after changed to c++ file, I got the compilation error.

Comment: Like @MikeSeymour commented, you should also set the function pointer to an actual function instead of NULL if you want this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your 2nd error your are getting becase you are returning a Pointer to function type instead of a int type.

If you want to return an int, call the function from the code :

```
return real_i_receive(f,t);
```

Notice the "()" which means a function call.

Regarding your guess : it doesn't matter if you are using C or C++ code, the libaries are all assembly code.

One difference between exporting C functions and C++ functions is the name mangling. You would rather export a function as a C function to be able to access it inside your library through unmagled name.

To export a function without name mangling it, you can use extern "C" .

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
return real_i_receive;
```

with

```
return real_i_receive(f, t);
```

As it is, the return type of your function is `int` but you're returning a function pointer.